# Deleting empty rows in a table in Excel with Office.js

Tags: ms-office, office-js

Sorry for what feels like a really  basic question.  I'm trying to iterate through an Excel table and delete any empty rows using the new add-in model. I'm fairly new to javascript and all the asynchronicity and callbacks are tying me in knots!

Since I think this is simple, I wondered if someone might be kind enough to post a quick code sample or suggestion has to the cleanest way to do it?  Sorry if I've missed it in the docs.

Many thanks in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you are looking for.

```js
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem('YourTableName').rows;
    rows.load("values"); // We'll need the rows values to check if they're empty.
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        // Important to go through the items in reverse fashion as deleting a row shifts the rest up.
        rows.items.reverse().forEach(function(row) {
            // row.values is a double array. Although, we know it can only contain one row.
            var isEmpty = row.values[0].every(function(col) {
                return col === "";
            });

            if (isEmpty) {
                row.delete();
            }
        });
    }).then(ctx.sync);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Hope that helps,

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Just a function built off of [@GabRoyers answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34010550/5079799)

```
async function Do_Remove_Empty_Rows_Tbl(context, TblNameStr) {
    var rows = context.workbook.tables.getItem(TblNameStr).rows;
    rows.load("values");
    await context.sync();
    rows.items.reverse().forEach(function (row) {
        var isEmpty = row.values[0].every(function (col) {
            return col === "";
        });
        if (isEmpty) {
            row.delete();
        }
    });
    return context;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you use the macro recorder facility to do the basic job. Then use that within a basic For Each Cell loop with a empty row test to do your job.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think that would result in recording a VBA macro?  I was aiming to do it in javascript using office.js.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.